# How to use C# pagecode for a Sitecore SPEAK Application

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-speak-ui

I am trying out the sitecore speak ui applications. I am able to develop simple applications using speak.

I don't find any reference to how can we build SPEAK Pagecode file using C#.

I want to retrieve the data and save simple form using C# pagecode file.

Can any one guide me with an example?

I looked into https://doc.sitecore.net/speak/development/use_pagecode . But its of no help. I would like to know how can we bind the c# file to the SPEAK application and how to invoke functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the page code you need to edit the presentation of your page item. In Sitecore Rocks, go to the presentation details of your page item and double-click on the **PageCode** component to open the properties. There are 2 fields, `PageCodeScriptFileName` - that is for a JavaScript based page code, and `PageCodeTypeName`, in there add your fully qualified name of your C# class.

[image]

Credits to this post by Martina [enter link description here](http://mhwelander.net/2014/07/01/speak-for-newbies-part-4-pagecode-and-javascript-libraries/)

Comment: How do you write this class, though? For example, how do you read data from your form fields?